# MySQL search Optimization for Search Fields

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have an MySQL database with 500,000 rows.

I have a list of 500,000 combination Strings such as First_Name and Last_Name.

I am trying to search the 500,000 rows with a similar query

```
select count(*) FROM data WHERE first='wadaw' AND last='wdvv';
```

The problem is that it takes too much time, I am using multiple threads and it doesn't seem to be very efficient considering the communication overhead between MySQL and the running time of the queries. I thought to start improve by changing the settings of my database to better fit my data and optimize MySQL database for it.

From my experience with search algorithms, an unsorted list would take n*log(n) with the most widely used methods and N with radix sort etc. which makes it n^2 or n^2log(n) for my case, which is not that good if you have 1,000,000 fields.

But with Binary search it would take Log(n) and thus n*log(n) for my case.

I am looking for a way to make the best out of my database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How long is the too long it is taking?... and does your table have indexes set up?

Comment: As it always happens with performance related questions to be able to even try to intelligently answer your question you have to be **a way more specific**. Edit your question and post the exact table schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE data`), the results of executing `SHOW INDEXES FROM data` and `EXPLAIN <your query>`

Comment: I am looking for answers of the type, take both first_name and last_name hash them with a hash function and use that as a key to search. Or a suggestion such as, Go to your database settings and make  the table automatically sort itself based on these two values.

Comment: Well, hashing the name wouldn't do you any good unless you had an index on the resulting hash column that you'd have to have stored in the table... Except that an index on a first/last name pair would likely work out the same.  Tables don't actually sort themselves, indices have an ordered list of rows in the table (sorta).  Is your set of first/last name pairs in the db itself (and not in your application layer)?  Doing this in the db would probably massively speed things up, too.  Like @peterm says - we need **WAY** more info.

Comment: @μακακας If someone tells you to provide more info and the best you can do is counter with your 3:17 comment you are not going to get much help. Not because it's rude (it is), but because the information is required.

Comment: appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an index for both fields you are using. In your example:

```
create index idx_data_name_last on data (first, last);
```

That will use just one index and so the time will be log(n) and not n*log(n).